# How to import a package from a different directory in the same program?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import

Lets say I have a directory tree that looks like this:

```
main -
     |
    lib-
       |
      core-
          |
         fun-
            |
          some_file
        stuff-
             |
        another_file
```

How could I import the modules from `some_file` into `another_file`? Everytime I try to do the importing (yes I know about __`init__.py`) I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "file.py", line 6, in <module>
    from some_file import some_method
ImportError: No module named some_file
```

Is it possible to import the modules into another file?

Comment: can you show the code of how you tried to import the module

Comment: @depperm isn't there a way to use `os.path.join` to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import using absolute or relative imports if all the directories that you're traversing are Python packages (with `__init__.py` file in them).

Assuming that you are running your program from the directory in which `main` package is, you'd import `some_file` module with:

```
import main.lib.core.fun.some_file
```

Otherwise you have to append to Python path before attempting import:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("......main/lib/core")

import fun.some_file
```

The second example assumes that fun is a Python package with `__init__.py` file in it.

Answer (score 0):

Just add an `__init__.py` file to the directory to make it be seen as a module:

```
main -
     |
    lib-
       |
      core-
          |
         fun-
            |
          some_file
          __init__.py
        stuff-
             |
        another_file
```

The `__init__.py` can be a blank file, all that matters is that it exists. Then, you can do `import fun.some_file`